# Writing to a csv in r function

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to write a function that writes an output to a csv file within that function.  I am trying to direct the csv file to a folder labeled "test" within the working directory.  When I run the function then use it, nothing happens.

This is the function:

```
SCTble <- function(dat, datname) {
y<-ddply(dat, .(Species, Country), summarize, Pounds = 
round(sum(Pounds), 0 ), Dollars = round(sum(Dollars),0), UnitValue = 
round((Dollars/Pounds),2))
y<-y%>%
mutate('Share Volume' = round(Pounds/sum(Pounds)*100,2))%>%
mutate('Share Value'= round(Dollars/sum(Dollars)*100,2))
datname<-as.data.frame(y)
return(datname)
write.csv(y, paste("test/",datname, ".csv"), row.names= TRUE)
  }
```

This is how I used the function:

`FshPelExcurSC <- SCTble(FshPelExcur,"FshPelExcurSC")`

When I go back and try the code separately outside the function, it works and the csv file appears in the folder I specified.  But for some reason when I call on the function, nothing happens.  The function does create the table, it shows up in my global environment, it just doesn't appear as a csv in the folder I'd like it to.

I have many tables to make, and I'd like to name them by the second argument that the function calls for when writing them to csv files.

I haven't found anything that addresses this particular problem in the SO question and answers, and am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: You've got the `write.csv` **after** the `return`, so the function never gets to the `write.csv`. `return` exits a function.

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman.  I moved the return after the write.csv, but now I'm getting this error:  `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))`

Comment: You've *overwritten* the passed-in `datname` with this line `datname<-as.data.frame(y)`, so your filename is being constructed by pasting the dataframe contents...

Comment: @Spacedman, thank you!  I removed that line and it works perfectly now.